# Difference between histogram and pandas value_count()

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I suppose both the pandas value_counts() and histogram gives the frequency of an item. I have a case where this is different. When I plot a histogram, I get two peaks as shown below,

```
d = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
d.hist()
d['value'].value_counts().nlargest(3)


200000000.0    906
20.0           219
10.0           158
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

[image]

But when I use value_counts(), I only get the value 200000000 as the most occurring one, but instead it should be something around 0.02. Can someone explain what exactly happens here. The sample data that I used is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MathewKevin/sample/main/sample.csv).

Answer (score 1):

A [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), gives you the counts over **bins**. This means the count/frequency of **consecutive groups of values**.

```
df['value'].plot.hist()
```

[image]

The (approximate) equivalent using a [bar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart), would be to first compute bins with [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
pd.cut(df['value'], bins=10).value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Output of `pd.cut(df['value'], bins=10).value_counts(sort=False)`:

```
(-199999.996, 20000000.004]       1523
(20000000.004, 40000000.003]         5
(40000000.003, 60000000.003]         9
(60000000.003, 80000000.002]         5
(80000000.002, 100000000.002]        0
(100000000.002, 120000000.002]       8
(120000000.002, 140000000.001]       0
(140000000.001, 160000000.001]       0
(160000000.001, 180000000.0]         0
(180000000.0, 200000000.0]         906
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

they are the same thing if you checked the csv file you will find that 200000000.0 is exactly 906 and that is what they both showing
but in the histogram they used apprev to the numbers 1e8

Answer (score 0):

Pandas hist may combine some values into the same bin. The default number of bins is 10. So, as long as you do not specify the number of bins, pandas will use 10 and try to fit the data accordingly.